# Ajax call to save data from grails show.gsp receiving "Session is Closed!" exception

Tags: jquery, ajax, hibernate, session, grails

I am trying to make an ajax call on a checkbox that will save or delete a user role to the database on clicking the check box.

ajax:

```
$('.roleCheckbox').click(function() {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

//var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

//alert($(this).attr("context") + "/userRole/addUserRole/");
var inputData = {userid: $(this).attr('userid'),
                    roleid: $(this).val()};

if(checked){
    //alert( $(this).attr("context") + "/userRole/addUserRole/");
    //ajax add userRole
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("context") + "/userRole/addUserRole/",
        method:"POST",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success updating role " + $(this.val()));
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            //alert("error updating role ");
        },
        complete: function() {
            //alert("complete");
        }
    });
}else{
    //ajax remove userRole
    alert("in unchecked condition: " + $(this).attr("context")  + "/userRole/addUserRole/");
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("context") + "/userRole/removeUserRole/",
        data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success deleting role " + $(this.val()));
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert("error deleting role " + $(this.val()) + " " + error);
        },
        complete: function() {

        }
    });
}
});
```

controller:

```
 @Transactional
def addUserRole() {

    def jsonObj = request.JSON

    UserService.addUserRole(jsonObj)


}
```

service:

```
@Transactional
def addUserRole(JSONObject jsonObj) {

    def currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

    UserRole.withTransaction{ status ->
        def user = User.get(jsonObj.userid)
        def role = Role.get(jsonObj.roleid)

        def userRole = new UserRole();

        userRole.user = user
        userRole.role = role

        userRole.validate();
        if(userRole.hasErrors()){
            flash.message = userRole.errors
            respond user
        }else{
            currentSession.save(userRole)
        }
    }

    currentSession.flush()

}
```

The problem is that when the controller function returns i get an error:

org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

Grails 3.2.0.M2

I've looked all over and cannot figure out how to manage these sessions correctly.

Thanks,

Lou

EDIT:

Adding render(status:200)  to the end of the controller made the ajax call return successfully,  however that is just masking the "Session is Closed!"  exception I am receiving.

I tried the suggestion of using .withTransaction instead of the .withNewSession 
in the service with the same result.

I think this may have to do more with the spring-security-plugin as even the grails scaffold created UserRoleController method to save() is issuing the "Session is Closed!" exception on save.

Can you update the UserRole (PersonAuthority) domain at runtime?

Comment: Try adding `render(status: 200)` after `UserService.addUserRole(jsonObj)` in your action.

Answer (score 0):

Don't manually flush the session. Let the Grails/Hibernate do this for you. Consider changing to this code:

```
@Transactional
def addUserRole(JSONObject jsonObj) {
    UserRole.withTransaction { status ->
        def user = User.get(jsonObj.userid)
        def role = Role.get(jsonObj.roleid)

        def userRole = new UserRole();

        userRole.user = user
        userRole.role = role

        userRole.validate()
        if (userRole.hasErrors()) {
            flash.message = userRole.errors
            return
        } else {
            currentSession.save(flush: true)
        }
    }    
}
```

Also, add `render(status: 200)` at the last in your action.